# Obtaining values from Zomato API data keys

Tags: python, api, zomato-api

I am currently trying to obtain the names and addresses of restaurants in Hayward from the "best_restaurant" list in the Zomato API.

I have tried

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

data = (response.json())

# print(data)

for item in data["best_rated_restaurant"]:
    print item["name"]
```

I am receiving the data for "best_rated_restaurant", but do not know how to get specific values within the data.

Does anyone know how I would go about retrieving information inside the data such as name, address, cuisine, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
for item in data["best_rated_restaurant"]:
    print item['restaurant']['name']
    print item['restaurant']['location']['address']
    print item['restaurant']['cuisines']
```